# MySQL Statement Displaying Values Even If NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `EMPLOYEE` & `DEPENDENT`. The employee `PK` is `SSN` and the foreign key for the dependent table is `ESSN`. I am trying to retrieve the name of all employees and the names of their dependent. If an employee does not have a dependent, I just need to display a blank value in the dependent column.

To retrieve the name of employees who have dependents, this is the statement I use:

```
SELECT 
      firstName AS "First Name", 
      lastName AS "Last Name",
      dependent_name AS "Dependent Name" 
FROM employee,dependent 
WHERE ssn=essn;
```

If somebody could guide me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need an *outer* join.  See [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `left join` to get all rows from the first table even if there are no matching in the second:

```
SELECT 
  firstName AS "First Name", 
  lastName AS "Last Name", 
  dependent_name AS "Dependent Name" 
FROM employee
LEFT JOIN dependent ON dependent.essn = employee.ssn;
```

I changed your implicit old-style join to an ANSI compliant explicit join too.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This worked like I wanted it to. I am going to dig into what a LEFT JOIN does to expand my knowledge. Will vote as best answer once I am able to.

Comment: @dhint4 The link that eggyal provided is a really good explanation.